# Google Ads Api Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, console-application, google-ads-api

I want to develop a console application that pulls all campaigns under adwords accounts using Google Ads Api.
But I could not pass the authentication step.

I do not fully understand whether I should use the Service Account or Desktop Application Flow for this process.

```
GoogleAdsConfig config = new GoogleAdsConfig()
            {
                DeveloperToken = "Dev_token",
                OAuth2Mode = Google.Ads.GoogleAds.Config.OAuth2Flow.APPLICATION,
                OAuth2ClientId = "client_Id",
                OAuth2ClientSecret = "secrret",
                OAuth2RefreshToken = " refresh_token", 
            };

GoogleAdsClient client = new GoogleAdsClient(config);

GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsService = client.GetService(Google.Ads.GoogleAds.Services.V10.GoogleAdsService);

googleAdsService.SearchStream(AdwordsClientId, query,
                delegate (SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse resp)
                {
                    foreach (GoogleAdsRow adsRow in resp.Results)
                    { 
                    }
                }
            );
```

When I try as above, I get the following error

Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""

What paths should i follow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`unauthorized_client` could have a couple of reasons. The most important ones that come to mind:

- Did you make sure that your client ID and client secret match?
- Have you activated the Google Ads API for the GCP project whose OAuth2 client you are using?